# Remove double quotes from function body

Tags: r

I have a function in `x` say `y <- function(x){x^2+9*x}`

I want to return as a string `x^2+9*x` with no leading/ trailing spaces as shown.

I tried the following:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
g   <- function(x){x^2+9*x}
y1 <- g %>%
    deparse_function_body(.) %>%
    str_replace(pattern = "[[:punct:]]", "") %>% 
    noquote(.) %>%
    str_trim(.)
y1
```

This returns `[1] ""    "x^2" ""` which is not what is required i.e. `[1] "x^2+9*x"`

Could anyone please show me the cleanest way of achieving this please?

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven! If you would like to post as an answer I can accept this formally. Also it is not obvious that deparse(g) returns a list right?

Comment: `deparse(g)` returns a character vector, each element is a line to the function.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `body()` with `deparse()`.  No packages needed.

```
deparse(body(g)[[2]])
# [1] "x^2 + 9 * x"
```

It seems like you were wanting to do something like this -

```
trimws(deparse(g)[3])
# [1] "x^2 + 9 * x"
```

I guess either one would work just fine.